# How to make a grid control in Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I want to create a CRUD window where I will list many records. How to produce something like this:

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me where to see "mock up" text ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the "Table" element in the "Mockup Text" category is the one that you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: That is really what I needed. This is a new feature or a missed it in April's version?

Comment: can you please tell me where to see "mock up" text ?