# Where to go to see "mockup" texts in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

This is my question: [How to make a grid control in Draw.io?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42972/how-to-make-a-grid-control-in-draw-io), but I don't know where to go to see "mockup" texts?....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I read an answer about how to make a table in Draw.io, I wanted to ask the same question. Because there were no answers, I had to find one myself. Thanks to sufficient caffeine concentration in my blood, the search was successful :) Here goes:

1. On the bottom of the "shapes" menu there is a button named "More shapes..." - click it.
   Alternatively, you can click the "View" menu on the toolbar, and then choose "Shapes...".
2. In the new "Shapes" window, find the "Software" part.
3. Check the box called "Mockups" and click OK.
4. In the main draw.io window, in shapes library You will see a lot of new "Mockup ..." categories. One of them is the desired "Mockup Text".
5. Enjoy :)